# JTable with file i/o and array list

Tags: java, swing, file-io, arraylist, jtable

In my program users input words along with their corresponding definition.
An example of this user defined object is [countenance, a person's face].
The user's words are stored in an array list which works with file i/o. 
However, each time I call the "prepareTable" method, the program 
adds duplicates of the words found in the text file to the array list. If you need to see more code, I can post it but for convenience/readability I only posted the prepareTable method. Why is my program duplicating the words? Is there something wrong with this method?

```
public void prepareTable ()
{
    readFromFile();
    for (int i = 0; i <= LibraryWordsList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
       tableData.setValueAt(LibraryWordsList.get(i).getWord(), i, 0);
       tableData.setValueAt(LibraryWordsList.get(i).getDefinition(), i, 1);  
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). So yes post more code

Answer (score 3):

If `tableData` refers to an instance of `DefaultTableModel`, you can invoke `setRowCount(0)` to clear the previous entries before adding new ones. You can get a reference to the table's `TableModel` by using the table's `getModel()` method.